# How to Trigger DataGridView CellEndEdit When A Cell Value Changes Programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview which updates the database on CellEndEdit method. On the stock code columns' cells when the user presses F10 a new list opens and the user can choose a new code. The value of my datagridview cell updates but CellEndEdit does not trigger. I have previously tried handling CellEndEdit whenever the user presses F10 on those cells but it fails(I believe my arguments etc are terribly wrong). I have looked at programmatically handling the event but it did not work. I was wondering how I can trigger CellEndEdit inside KeyDown Method.

```
    private void dataGridView2_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {//F10 A BASILDIĞINDA EGER STOK KODU HUCRELERİNDEN BASILDIYSA STOK KODLARI AÇILIYOR
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10)
        {
            int satir = dataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            int sutun = dataGridView2.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

            if (sutun == 7)
            {

                // dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] = STOKKODU0COMBOBOX;
                using (StokKoduListeForm stokkodulisteform = new StokKoduListeForm(secilenveritabani))
                {
                    stokkodulisteform.ShowDialog();
                    dataGridView2[sutun, satir].Value = (stokkodulisteform.stokkodugetir());


                }


            }}
```

I have tried

```
  DataGridViewCellEventArgs a = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(sutun, satir);
                   dataGridView2_CellEndEdit_1(dataGridView2, a);
```

Inside the using but it shows a messagebox from another form somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Cell value does not trigger the EndEdit event. Calling the BeginEdit and then by an EndEdit may trigger the EndEdit event. Please change the code like below and try.

```
using (StokKoduListeForm stokkodulisteform = new StokKoduListeForm(secilenveritabani))
        {
            dataGridView2.BeginEdit(true);
            stokkodulisteform.ShowDialog();
            dataGridView2[sutun, satir].Value = (stokkodulisteform.stokkodugetir());
            dataGridView2.EndEdit();

        }
```